# Suggestion Strip of Soft Keyboard hides part of the layout

Tags: java, android, kotlin, keyboard

I've tried virtually every solution out there for soft keyboard covering part of the view when pops up, on further investigation I found that it's not the keyboard but the suggestions strip that's covering the layout.
But disabling the suggestion strip from the settings of the keyboard seems the only solution.

I've tried some hacks which add padding at runtime when the keyboard pops up but none seems to work.

[This screenshot will explain it better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBjzx.png)

The below code snippet is from my BottomSheetDialog:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/design_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/feedback_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/recognition_text_box_border_drawable"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="@string/manager_recognition_edit_text_hint"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:maxLength="200"
        android:maxLines="24"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/award_badge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/feedback_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/feedback_text"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/trophy_golden" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/award_badge_item"
        layout="@layout/award_badge_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/feedback_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/feedback_text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/feedback_text">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_recognition"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/medium_button_height"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@android:string/cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/send_recognition"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/medium_button_height"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="@string/send_recognition" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you paste here xml and java code?
B'coz I have design some layout and open the layout into alert dialog (gravity= bottom), Suggestion strip is showing above the soft keyboards (no part is hide from soft keyboard)

Comment: @mdroid23 i've added the xml code for the bottomsheetdialog

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your manifest activity tag where you are opening keyboard

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Comment: thanks, but as I stated earlier, I've tried all possible workarounds including this but none of them worked till now.